# Recreating security on a restored database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, scripting, permissions

We are often tasked with backing up and restoring databases between our production and development environments.  The most tedious part of this task is recreating the database users "one by one" in SQL when the servers are in different zones.

I am looking for a way to retrieve all users on a specific database (Windows users and groups, SQL users and roles) along with their current permission levels and then somehow use those results to recreate the permissions once the database is restored.

Can anyone help get me started in the right direction?

Regards,

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

This url should help you get started.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992
Its a combination of transferring logins, i personally use SSIS for this and then creating the users based on the link above.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should:
Create a temp table that holds queries to be executed
Load that temp table with queries to add all the logins
Load that temp table with queries to add all the users (for logins)
Load that temp table with queries to add all the permissions(for tables)

Then it prints out all those statements, which you should be able to copy to a query window in the new environment and execute.

Hopefully this is a good starting point for you.

```
if object_id('dbo.tempUsers') is not null
Drop table dbo.tempUsers

Create table tempUsers(ID int identity , Queries Varchar(255))

Insert into tempUsers(Queries)
select 'Create login [' + su.name + '] with password ' + su.password 
FROM sys.sysusers su

Insert into tempUsers(Queries)
select 'Create user [' + su.name + '] for login [' + su.password + ']'
FROM sys.sysusers su

Insert into tempUsers(Queries)
select 'GRANT ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as
+ ' ON ' + s.name + '.' + o.name + ' TO '  + '[' + dpr.name + ']'
FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
where o.type = 'U'

declare @count int, @max int, @query Varchar(255)
set @count =1
set @max = (Select max(ID) from tempUsers)
set @query = (Select Queries from tempUsers where ID = @count)

while(@count < @max)
begin
print(@query)
set @count += 1
set @query = (Select Queries from tempUsers where ID = @count)
end
```